# When is the half-sum of positive roots a character?

Tags: representation-theory, reductive-groups

I am trying to understand how the Weyl character formula works for GL_n.

In Milne's Algebraic groups, he gives the character formula in the following setting :
Let $G$ be a connected split reductive group over a field, let $T$ be a maximal split torus and $B$ a Borel containing it. Denote $\rho$ to be the half-sum of the corresponding positive roots.
Just before theorem 22.50, Milne quotes Iversen's "the geometry of algebraic groups" (1976) to say that because $\mathrm{Pic}(G)$ is trivial, $\rho$ is actually a character of $T$, which then allows him to state and prove the character formula.

In Iversen, the same thing is said.

But for $G=GL_n$, according to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1999823/picard-groups-and-fundamental-groups-of-connected-algebraic-groups) the Picard group vanishes, however the half-sum is only a character if $n$ is odd, since it equals $\left(\frac{n-1}{2}, \frac{n-3}{2},...,\frac{1-n}{2}\right)$ in the standard basis of $X(T)$, for the standard torus and standard Borel.

I can't figure out which part of this is wrong. Is there an extra hypothesis I did not see for the result ? Is the Picard group of $GL_n$ not trivial ? Or am I making a stupid mistake computing the half-sum of positive roots ?

Thank you for answering.

Comment: This is an explicit assumption: "We now assume that Pic(G) = 0". However, the Weyl character formula still makes *sense* for $GL_n$ because, although $\rho$ is not in the character lattice and neither the numerator nor the denominator of the formula are proper characters, the quotient *is* (this can be made formal by working in an appropriate field of fractions: this is done in Janten's Algebraic Groups for example).

Comment: Thanks for your comment ! I understand that $\mathrm{Pic}(G)=0$ is an assumption, but what I don't get is that this assumption seems to be satisfied for $\mathrm{GL}_n$, even though $\rho$ is not a proper character in this case

Comment: Ah I see what you mean - in that case I would say there is an error - one would really need to assume $G$ is semisimple or simply-connected or something to reliably get that $\rho$ is in the character lattice.